# Is there a way to give focus to Chrome search result?

Tags: google-chrome, find, focus

It is well known that one can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find textual content in the webpage, but after I found what I need, is there a way to give focus to the search result, so that if the result is a link or a button, I can quickly click the link/button by pressing <kbd>space</kbd>/<kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Comment: I think Ctrl+F (or F3) only finds the text you enter and highlights it. The highlighting isn't the equivalent of focusing, IMO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Google chrome, you can start a search in the active tab by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> Or <kbd>F3</kbd>, input the text you want to find and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to find

[image]

You can loop through the search results by pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Once you found the text you want, if its a link or a button, you can navigate to it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Hope it helps.

Comment: Once you type the text you are searching for, there is no need to press Enter. The first result will be highlighted and if you press CTRL+ENTER it will open it (assuming it is a link).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be interested in a keyboard only browser such as Conkeror that operates primarily using keyboard-shortcuts.

Through a quick search I found an extension for chrome called Vimium which appears to be similar in that it adds vim-like keyboard-shortcuts in order to navigate your webpage which would include methods to follow links. (Conkeror has you enter a 'follow link' mode which results in each link on the screen appearing with a number next to it.  You type the number and enter to follow the link)

Alternatively, in vanilla chrome (or any other browser), if you search with ctrl-f and the result is a link, after pressing esc to exit the search, the found phrase will still be highlighted.  Just press enter to follow.