# Is there a way to give focus to browser search result?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, internet-explorer

It is well known that one can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find textual content in the webpage, but after I found what I need, is there a way to give focus to the search result, so that if the result is a link or a button, I can quickly click the link/button with keyboard?

I have asked this question previously:
[Is there a way to give focus to Chrome search result?](https://superuser.com/questions/963380/is-there-a-way-to-give-focus-to-chrome-search-result)

However, I found that the combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> is not working on Firefox and Internet Explorer. Is there similar key combination for IE and Firefox? Or is this a Chrome only feature?

Answer (score 4):

The find bar should be closed first, only then user can quickly click the link via keyboard. This works not just for Firefox, but also other web browsers including Vivaldi and Edge.

[image: Find and focus link in Firefox]

The steps are described as follows.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to show the Find toolbar at bottom of its window (also accessible from menu bar: **Edit > Find**) and identify what user wants to find
2. Type a keyword to find on existing page, so that the matching keyword will be highlighted
3. Close the toolbar by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, so that the matching keyword will have focus with dotted borders after the highlight is gone
4. Finally, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to "click" the link

**HTML button**: User can't click on an HTML button without a cursor. Even the keyword is matched with the text on that button, it is impossible to click it using the keyboard.

Nowadays, an HTML button tend to be replaced by an HTML link (hyperlink) and decorate it like a button using Cascading Style Sheets, which is more accessible. This means, this answer will remain valid for text buttons on modern Web.